# Does Windows firewall stop attack use bandwidth?

Tags: windows, firewalls, ddos, internet, protection

If I block all the international traffic except an IP range and an attacker starts a DDoS attack on my IP, will it effect on my bandwidth?

Comment: Where is this firewall? If it is anywhere close to you, then yes, you will be affected.

Answer (score 4):

Firewalls do not block DDoS. DDoS is a massive flood of traffic to your site/servers/network. As your firewall starts to deny each one of the traffic flows, not only will your bandwidth be affected, but your firewall will fail, too.

The remedy for DDoS is to reduce the flood as close to the sources as possible. This tends to be at the ISP level.

Comment: Just to add to this, remember that a DDOS can also be generated from within the network, like in a smurf attack ref: http://blog.cloudflare.com/content/images/smurf_attack_diagram.png.scaled500.png

Comment: @AnthonyRussell while true, traffic floods within a network tend to go by different names than DDoS.